# Package con procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, oracle

Debo realizar un Procedimiento almacenado que deberá ser ejecutado por TODOS los programas construidos, de acuerdo a la siguiente notación:

Características principales:

1. Cuando ocurra algún error durante la ejecución del proceso. Los errores deben ser almacenados en la tabla `ERROR_CALC_VENTA` indicando el programa en donde ocurrió el error y el mensaje de error Oracle.
2. Para la columna `correl_error` usar el objeto secuencia `SEQ_ERROR.`

Tengo dudas acerca de como puedo realizar ese ejercicio, si alguien pudiera ayudarme

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, da un [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y revisa [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad. Para poder ayudarte es necesario que muestres lo que has realizado hasta el momento, cuales son los errores que se te presentan, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta en este momento suele ser bastante general. Pero te daré una idea sobre lo que puedes hacer.

1. Construye la tabla en donde vas a guardar tus bitácoras de error
2. Construye un procedimiento el cual la función que realice sea insertar los registros en tu tabla
3. En cada método que crees, usa la instrucción try catch. En donde deberás aplicar lo siguiente:

por ejemplo:

```
public void metodo()
{
try
    {
       //recorrido del programa
     }
  // en caso de que falle se irá a catch
catch (CustomException ex)
     {
      // llamas al procedimiento almacenado que construiste y envías el mensaje que te arroja de error al procedimiento para que te lo insertes en la tabla.
     }
}
```

Comment: la respuesta que da es Java, y si hablan de procedimiento almacenado tal vez lo que se espera es en PL/SQL.